# Has Trump previously engaged in speculation about "cultural marxism"?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

Trump recently retweeted this [tweet by Charlie Kirk](https://twitter.com/charliekirk11/status/1069811169010089984) which claims that:

> They want to cover up the middle class rebellion against cultural Marxism

Has Trump previously mentioned the "cultural marxism" theory, or gone into depth about what he understands it to be?

Comment: Looks like a clean twitter feed for DJT, but this is 'nice' https://twitter.com/bolsonarosp/status/1025718449425788929?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

It appears not.

There was a related media report, but Donald Trump seems not to have invoked the subject himself.    [This report](https://foreignpolicy.com/2017/08/10/heres-the-memo-that-blew-up-the-nsc/) claims to include a copy of a memo that was written in May 2017 by a National Security Counsel staffer.  That memo made reference to cultural Marxism.

It is said the memo "ended up on Trump's desk" (more likely the chief of staff's.)   [The staffer who wrote it was fired.](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2017/08/a-national-security-council-staffer-is-forced-out-over-a-controversial-memo/535725/)

Comment: Doesn't everyone working for Trump get fired? (statistically speaking) :p